# polymorphic and type changing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have Users model in my app with something like

```
belongs_to :account, :polymorphic => true, :dependent => :destroy
```

And some special account types like Admin or Editor

```
class Admin < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :account, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Editor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :account, :dependent => :destroy
end
```

Is there any clean method to change User type from Editor to Admin? If I do something like

```
admin = Admin.new
User.first.account = admin
user.save
admin.save
```

There is still an old entry for editor type in the database.

Comment: If you are using STI, there should be a varchar column named `type` which specified the model name (eg. `Admin` or `Editor`). If you could change this field, it should be done. (but I did not tested this so this is just a comment not answer :D)

Comment: The problem is I don't want old entries in db.

Comment: Are you admin records and editors records all stored in the same accounts table? Then just to update the `type` column from `Editor` to `Admin`. No new record is generated at all.

Comment: It doesn't look like he's using STI, so I don't think it's as easy as changing the type attribute.

Comment: Oh, @luke you are right. I missed the `< ActiveRecord::Base` for both admin and editor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `:dependent => :destroy` will only delete the associated object when the object itself is destroyed. You aren't destroying the user record, just changing one of its attributes, so this functionality is never triggered.

To destroy it yourself, do something like

```
user = User.first
user.account.destroy
user.account = Admin.create
user.save
```